# Count the number of occurrences each combination of values in two columns of a pandas dataframe and make a barplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization

I have two columns in my dataframe which contain binary values. project_is_approved column has value 1 if the project is approved or else 0 
numbers_in_summary_or_not: there was another column(named as "summary") which had text data based on which this column is constructed. if there was a number used in the text data in summary the corresponding row will have value 1 or else it will be 0

Now, I want to visualise my data based on these two columns:

```
numbers_in_summary_or_not,project_is_approved
```

I think bar plots should work, I think I need 4 bar plots showing 4 
features

numbers_in_summary_or_not =0 and project_is_approved =0 : 1st barplot numbers_in_summary_or_not =0 and project_is_approved =1 : 2nd barplot numbers_in_summary_or_not =1 and project_is_approved =0 : 3rd barplot numbers_in_summary_or_not =1 and project_is_approved =1 : 4th barplot –

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *visualize*? plot/scatter them? histogram?

Comment: I think bar plots should work, I think I need 4 bar plots showing 4 features 


numbers_in_summary_or_not =0 and project_is_approved =0 : 1st barplot
numbers_in_summary_or_not =0 and project_is_approved =1 : 2nd barplot
numbers_in_summary_or_not =1 and project_is_approved =0 : 3rd barplot
numbers_in_summary_or_not =1 and project_is_approved =1 : 4th barplot

Comment: Please, add this clarification in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be that your're trying to do something like plot the counts of the combinations of those two columns?

in such a case you could add a column combining the two like so

```
# a series to use for counting- formatted as cat1_cat2
ts = (df['numbers_in_summary_or_not'].astype(str) + '_' + df['project_is_approved'].astype(str))
# and plot the counts of the groups like
ts.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: no problem! In the future, when you post a question, try to make the title a bit more descriptive, and if possible include an example with toy data to avoid down votes. I'm going to edit your title a bit to reflect the question more completely.